# Managing simple state in Caliburn Micro WinRT 8.1: navigate to previously active page

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

I'm creating a WinRT 8.1 app based onto Caliburn.Micro (alpha2) and I'm implementing a simple state management mechanism for it. All it needs is saving a couple of name/value pairs for each of its two or three pages, and restore the current page when resumed. So I'm using the strategy summarized below; given that it seems there is no predefined mechanism for CM/WinRT, it would be interesting to get any community advice on this, or this might hopefully be useful for RT newcomers like me.

1) I define an **interface** (`IHaveSimpleState`) to be implemented by VMs having some simple state to be saved and restored. The state is represented by a dictionary where each value is a string, representing any serialized value, and the interface just has 2 methods, one for saving its state into this dictionary, and another to resume it from the dictionary. All my stateful VMs (each corresponding to a view) implement this.

2) In my **app**.cs (which derives from `Caliburn.Application`), I create a `List<WeakReference<IHaveSimpleState>>` to keep track of all the VMs requiring state management: in the `GetInstance` override which instantiates the VMs (using CM simple container) I add to this list each newly generated instance implementing `IHaveSimpleState`.

3) for **saving** state: in the app `OnSuspending` override, I cycle through all the VMs in this list, and invoke their `SaveState` method to collect data about their state in a common dictionary. Once the loop is complete, I get `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` and I copy these data into its `Values` dictionary, thus effectively saving them.

4) for **restoring** state: in the app `OnResuming` override and in the `OnActivated` override (in the latter case, only if `args.PreviousExecutionState` is equal to `Running`, i.e. the app was not terminated by user nor crashed), I invoke a `ResumeState` method which cycles through all the VMs in the list and invokes their `LoadState` method to load the state from application data local settings.

All this seems to work fine, I only miss a point: *what's the right place to restore the current "page"*, i.e. to tell Caliburn to navigate to the VM behind the view active at the time of suspension? I tried to do this at the end of my `ResumeState` method (nr.4), but it seems too early, as when I try to navigate to a VM I get an exception telling me that the corresponding view could not be found. Here is the relevant code for this method:

```
private void ResumeState()
{
    // ... state is a dictionary wrapper class with state data

    // restore state for each tracked VM
    foreach (WeakReference<IHaveSimpleState> reference in _statefulViewModels)
    {
        IHaveSimpleState stateful;
        if (reference.TryGetTarget(out stateful)) stateful.LoadState(state);
    }

    // move to the page which was current when the state was saved
    string sType = state.Get(APP_CURRENTVM_KEY, null);
    if (sType != null)
    {
        // not so elegant...
        INavigationService navigation = IoC.Get<INavigationService>();
        Type t = Type.GetType(sType);
        navigation.NavigateToViewModel(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange - I can see that this might happen if the app was only just loaded (new instance) since the bootstrapper may not have kicked in and registered all the views, but then again I don't know RT so I can't for certain tell you what the order of events are when an app is resuming. Have you tried putting this in the bootstrapper in the `Configure` method (after the base.Configure() is called?) - I'm thinking that at least this will be after app initialisation so the views should be ready to go

Comment: Thanks, but if I try to insert the navigate-to-VM code at the end of Configure (even after calling base.Configure(); is this anyway required in overriding the Configure method in CM?), all what I get is another exception telling me that IoC has not yet been configured.

Comment: There is an interesting article by the creator of CM [here](http://caliburnmicro.com/announcements/application-state-part-3/). It proposes some ideas but does not provide implementation. It opens a discussion though. Also have a look at [this](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/95)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and seems to work, but I feel a bit unsecure about the robustness of my app given that the lifecycle handling in CM for 8.1 does not seem to be clearly documented, so I'd like to get comments or corrections from the community. First override the `PrepareViewFirst` method:

```
protected override void PrepareViewFirst(Frame rootFrame)
{
    _container.RegisterNavigationService(rootFrame);
}
```

Then in the `OnLaunched` override, where before I just called `DisplayRootView<MainView>()`, I test the args to check whether we are resuming from suspended state, and if so I navigate to the previously active page; else I just go as before:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    bool bResumed = false;
    if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Suspended)
    {
        AppSimpleState state = LoadState();
        string sType = state.Get(APP_CURRENTVM_KEY);
        if (sType != null)
        {
            INavigationService navigation = IoC.Get<INavigationService>();
            Type t = Type.GetType(sType);
            Debug.Assert(t != null);
            navigation.NavigateToViewModel(t);
            bResumed = true;
        } //eif
    }

    if (!bResumed) DisplayRootView<MainView>();
}
```

Comment: When I get round to writing some RT apps I'll come back and let you know if I found a better way to do this - I'm currently writing some droid stuff so not quite got to the RT part, if you do find a better place to put this, please do update. The alternative (and something I often do) is to look at the CM source on CodePlex and just run through it from the bootstrapper onwards. It's well written and easy to follow and so you will learn plenty about the order of events.